# what kind of relationship do child components have with components in react?

Tags: inheritance, reactjs

I'm currently writing a paper on my react frontend and I'm struggeling to find the right verb for the interaction between child-components and components in react.

For example:

**"I have a table component which ?inherits? from the child components tableHeader and tableBody."**

Is the use of inheritance correct here or how should I describe it?

EDIT:
Here is a example code of my table

```
import React from 'react';
import TableHeader from './tableHeader';
import TableBody from './tableBody';

// Stateless Functional Component

const Table = ({ columns, sortColumn, onSort, data }) => {
  return (
    <table className="table">
       <TableHeader
          columns={columns}
          sortColumn={sortColumn}
          onSort={onSort}
       />
       <TableBody columns={columns} data={data} />
    </table>
  );
};



export default Table;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inheriting from children is highly unnatural :) 
I would say that a Table component likely *wraps* or *contains* TableHeader and TableBody components, and renders them as its children.